# Syncing UITableview with subscription data

Tags: swift, uitableview, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I have a **Tableview** with somewhat complex operations where
sections are inserted and updated in realtime though **GraphQl subscriptions**.

At the moment I'm having some problems with **race conditions**. 
When i receive new data through the subscription i parse it into my Model and update the tableview with insertions and updating the content and size on some existing cells.

The problem arrises when i get data faster then i can finish the previous update in the table resulting in an **"invalid number of sections"** crash.

I believe a solution is to **serial/wait** the sequence **subscription -> model -> tableview**.

Ive tried to get this to work with various concurrency methods such as, **semaphore, sync, barrier, dispatch group**. but have not been able to successfully figure it out.

If i try to simplify, the sequence of events transpires something like this.

//Model

```
subscription { data in 

 //should not start parsing new data until previous data has been drawn in table to avoid missmatch in model and table

 parse(data)

}

func parse(data) {
//do stuff like update datamodel 
figureOutWhatToUpdateInTable(data) { (insertSet, reloadSet) in
  delegate.updateTableView(insertSet, reloadSet)
 }
//do stuff
}
```

//VC

```
func updateTableView(insertSet, reloadSet) {

 tableView.beginUpdates()
 CATransaction.begin()

//once a new section is inserted we need to update content of some sections  
 CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {

  reloadSet.forEach { (index: Int) in

   let section = tableView.headerView(forSection: index)

    section.updateData(data[index]) {
 // call begin/end to make tableview get height                                                
     tableView.beginUpdates()                                            
     tableView.endUpdates()

// now im ready to parse new data into my model

      }
   })

 }

tableView.insertSections(insetSet, with: .top)
CATransaction.commit()
tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

basically i need to wait for **section.updateData** to finish before **parse(data)** processes any new data from the subscription

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solid solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue with rare race conditions, in a complex tableview like yours

Answer (score 0):

You can use at this case `DispatchGroup`

```
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()

    // do some stuff (1)

    group.leave()

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        // do stuff after 1
    }
```

After call `group.leave()` group avtomaticaly execute STUFF at `group.notify` Block

Comment: I dont see how this would solve the problem. How would a dispatch group like this fix the race condition?